# FileSystem.CopyFile user actions

Tags: filesystems, file-copying

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  In my HTML View, I am using the standard Windows file input

```
<input style="border:thin solid #ccc;width:270px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" type="file" name="Name" id="Name"/>
```

In the Controller I am using the FileSystem.CopyFile() method found in Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.

```
FileSystem.CopyFile(fileName, fileDirectory +"\\" + attachments.Name, UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

It's working fine.  However, I need to know what selection the user makes on the dialog box.  How can I trap whether the user has selected "Copy & Replace", "Don't Copy", "Copy and Keep both files"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, the dialog takes care of this and doens't return the chosen option. You might want to rethink this. An option would be to create your own "Copy File" dialog.